# What does each color mean in Chrome performance monitor?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

On picture below i select only one item – CPU usage, but instead one red line, as I expected, I get several different lines on chart.
Can anyone explain this colors, please?

[image: profiler]

Comment: There should be a key that tells you. For instance orange is scripting. The darker purple is rendering. etc.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the close reason is absurd.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe this will help:

[image]

You should be able to find the key to your specific scenario under the summary tab. As pointed out by @recursive, you will find the summary tab under the Performance section of Chrome's developer tools

Comment: For anyone trying to find it like I was, the "summary" tab is under the performance section, not in the console drawer where the graph is.

Answer (score 4):

Purple color indicates the layout. It means that your CPU usage is related to `Layout` step of rendering. Try resizing the window and you will again get this pink color. The orange color is for scripting. As stated in the above comment. There should be a key indicating the purpose of the color.

Though it made me curious what is causing such heavy layout calculations like that.

Comment: Thank you.
It's a result of profiling bad optimised dropdown+autocomplete vueJs component.

Answer (score 0):

| color | action |
| --- | --- |
| yellow | `scripting` |
| purple | `rendering` |
| green | `painting` |
| blue | `loading` |
| gray | `other` |